# Is my answer actually wrong or not?

Tags: discussion, voting, specific-answer

Well I try to help when I have time, today I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33353946/exit-while-loop-using-null) where another user is downvoting every answer. I'm not sure about what to do and a war is starting in the comments of the answer (which I guess is bad for the site or answer in general).

I'm not a certified Java programmer, I'm still a student and sometimes I learn A LOT from these kind of questions, that's why I like answering them.

I have documented and explained the reason behind my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33354013/2180785), however this user hasn't added an answer yet, but I'm not sure if it would be better to delete my answer or leave it there.

As I said, I'm still lacking a lot of knowledge, probably my answer is in fact wrong, so if anyone could help me know if it's actually wrong or not, so I'd better delete it or keep it.

Comment: Downvotes are anonymous, you have no way of knowing it it's the same user voting on each answer.

Comment: @Paulie_D I know that, but that's not my question, is my answer actually wrong? I'm more worried about the discussion that was generated in the comments than for the downvote. -2 points with my rep isn't that much.

Comment: You have a user who seems very knowledgeable telling you that it is indeed wrong... instead of throwing the discussion to meta, why not talk with the user talking about your answer? (he's being polite, not being insulting or pushing back, so.... what's the issue with talking to him?)

Comment: The OP stating that he tried your answer and it didn't work is some pretty convincing evidence that the answer doesn't work.  I didn't read the question or the answer, but it certainly seems to not be a suitable answer.

Comment: First of all, thanks for answering questions! (I don't think that has been communicated to you yet.) *It is always possible that you give a bad answer*. It has happened to me, and (probably) to everyone else too - and that includes Jon Skeet and Joel Spolsky. Nevertheless, that discussion is not meta-material; hence the less-than-lukewarm reception you got over here. Don't be disappointed - if I am right, the discussion under your question ought to have you taught something new. But don't be afraid to answer - if you get it wrong, There Will Be Downvotes but usually explanations as well.

Comment: Sure that you can get some technical feedback, but Meta is not for this kind of question... "How can I improve my answer?" or related, but not about your programming correctness

Comment: How exactly is this a duplicate?...This is really asking about a specific answer, but this isn't really about a generic policy.

Comment: @Makoto: I was the one initially closing this as a duplicate. Frakcool is asking about a specific answer, and the question is "what is wrong with that answer" – which ought not be discussed in Meta. But it was a duplicate of the second question, "I'm not sure if it would be better to delete my answer or leave it there".

Comment: @Jongware:  There's still valuable discussion to be had here, considering that the user is both new to Stack Overflow and didn't think that they were particularly wrong on an answer.  On a case-by-case basis, I think it's okay to discuss what happened on a particular question, or what would make a particular answer attract downvotes more.  I admit I glossed over the "should I delete it" part pretty handily, but by the time I finished answering, the answer was deleted *anyway*.  The dupe felt more like a boilerplate response, which I don't think would've really helped anyone else in this spot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't consider myself a Java *expert* by any means, but I've been doing this for about three years and I've been haunting the Java tag for longer.

That said, I don't think your answer is necessarily *wrong*, but I don't see any completeness to it.  Specifically, there's an unknown in what's assigned to `test`, since it's being reused as `inputs[0]` later on in the code.  The OP hasn't provided us a sample of what their input would be, so I can't be confident that your answer satisfies the question.

I *might* personally downvote something like this since it's an attempt to answer an incomplete question.  Instead of trying to answer the question as stated, my personal preference would be to seek clarification for the root problem.  Providing feedback on the other answers and explaining why this doesn't really answer anything or is otherwise incomplete is helpful, too.

Comment: Next time I'll be more carefull in first clarifying everything then. Thanks. I'm sorry for attracting this kind of questions here on Meta, I'm not really into this part of SOF, I thought it might be a good place to clarify, since **I** felt like the other user was being kind of rude, probably 'cause english isn't my mother language so I might have misunderstood something. In any case I opted to delete my answer since it wasn't full or clear enough to solve OP's question. And no, I wasn't asking it here because of a downvote but because I wanted to improve.

Comment: @Frakcool:  That's cool; I'm happy to help.  Glad to see that you want to improve; that's what really counts for me.

Comment: I come to SOF everyday, sometimes there are questions that I can answer myself, others where I need to do some research, and others where just I can't help but I read at questions and answers. I learn from everything I can, as I said I'm still a student, but 90% of what I know, I've learnt it from myself here at SOF. I'll really try to improve at SOF and at Meta from now on too. :)